# Can I do this with Drupal and Organic Groups?

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

Basically I have a site in which I want my clients to be owners of a group, and then anonymous users can add nodes through their group and my clients will receive notification if someone adds a node in their group.

Basically the service is a lead generation service so in effect the content type is a landing page and when anonymous users go to put their details in, dependent on which group they do it through, the client will receive the notification.

i.e.  My clients group is www.example.com/group1 and they send out a link with their URL to generate some leads.
example.com/group1/node/add/landing-page

Once this node has been created, will it be possible to notify the group1 owner (I assume if I set the correct Rules)?

On top of this, I want the group1 owner to be able to login and see a Views display of all the nodes that have been created in their group.

I assume Organic Groups is the wway to go here, but I may be mistaken - any hep would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this has dramatically changed in D7, I don't think you're going to be able to let anonymous users post into Groups. The whole concept and structure of OG relies on users being logged in and identifiable.

In other words, I think you have to be a member of a Group to post in it, and anonymous (user 0) can never belong to a Group.